# How to create Login application in rails 6 using spine.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, spine.js

I want to create Ruby on Rails(version 6) application using spine.js as a front end. I am not familiar with spine.js.

Can anyone help me to integrate spine.js in rails 6 application.

Comment: https://github.com/maccman/spine.rails3

Answer (score 0):

You can check other compatible javascript frontend framework with rails 6 which may more suitable with your application.

Check below link.
https://hackr.io/blog/10-best-javascript-frameworks-2019